# C++11 variable type that acts like a literal initializer_list?

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

The expression `{"a", "b"}` seems to allow implicit conversion to a container of `string`s but if I first assign it to a variable, the conversion seems to be disallowed. Is there any way around that?

```
const char a[] = "a";
const char b[] = "b";
const char c[] = "c";

// Works
set<string> s1{a, b, c};
s1 = {a,b,c};

const auto abc = {a, b, c};

// no matching function for call ...
set<string> s2(abc);
s2 = abc;
```

Example code and error message [here](http://ideone.com/6aAj28):

EDIT: I can't make any of `a`, `b`, `c` or `abc` use string as they are run-time constructed and this won't work for my case.

Comment: that's because the `string` class has an overload for `const char *` where a `const char []` clearly doesn't.

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you elaborate? --- (BTW, the type of abc in that example end up being `const std::initializer_list<const char* const>`)

Comment: @user2485710 IIRC `const char *` and `const char []` are actually the same type.

Comment: the type of `abc` is `std::initializer_list<char const*>` you writing too many `const`.

Comment: ok, and where is the overload for the `initializer_list` ? Why you are assuming that passing a variable of type `initializer_list` to the constructor will work ?

Comment: @user2485710 `std::set` have a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`. The problem here is that the OP passes a `std::initializer_list<const char*]>` when the constructor wants a `std::initializer_list<std::string>`.

Comment: @BCS An array of two characters and a pointer to a character are *not* the same type. The types are compatible, because the array decays to a pointer, but they are not the same.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, infact I'm not surprised that this code doesn't do what is supposed to, there are 2 possible fixes, or you remove `auto` and express `abc` as a `const std::initializer_list<std::string>`, or you keep `auto` and use the type `std::string` for the 3 `a` `b` `c`.

Comment: `{"a", "b"}` is *not* an expression - it's a syntactic entity known as a *braced-init-list*. If you expect it to behave like an expression, you will be surprised in many cases.

Comment: For reason not under my control, `abc` can't use any type that will be constructed at run-time (I'm making the assumption that the compiler is smart enough to build `initializer_list<const chat*>` into the readonly segment).

Comment: @user2485710: The compiler claims that you are wrong re the type of `abc`. I think I'll trust it to know what it is doing. http://ideone.com/6aAj28

Comment: @Casey: Anything that can be used as an r-value is some kind of expression (e.g. a literal expression like `5`). In this case, it's a braced-init-list expression.

Comment: @BCS No, it's not. The grammar clearly and unambiguously states what an expression is. braced-init-list is a separate rule. As an example, the grammar explicitly has to state that a jump-statement can be `return`, optionally followed by an expression, followed by a semicolon, or `return`, followed by a braced-init-list, by a semicolon. It wouldn't have to do this if a braced-init-list were already an expression. braced-init-list also uses different rules from expressions in other contexts. For example, a type can be immediately followed by a braced-init-list, but not by an expression.

Comment: @hvd: then substitute "a syntactic entity that can be used as an r-value" everywhere I used "an expression". I'm referring to the former. If you know of a more concise and descriptive term I'll use that.

Comment: @BCS But when @Casey commented that `{"a", "b"}` is not an expression, that was referring to the standard's definition of expression. And I agree with that comment, it's important to understand the difference. For a practical example, `auto x = { 3, 4 };` may be valid, but `auto y = { 5, 6. };` is not, even though `Foo z = { 5, 6. };` could be valid depending on the definition of `Foo`. I don't have a better term that covers both braced-init-list and expression, I wouldn't think to look for a term that covers both. :)

Comment: There are plenty of syntactically valid expressions that are semantically errors. That makes a rather weak justification for the standard to exclude them from expressions. (A better one would be to allow expression to all have a well defined type that is independent of context but to allow braced-init-list to act differently in different contexts, which would explain my current problem.)

Comment: @BCS The syntax would actually get very complicated if you treat braced-init-list as an expression, too. An expression can be used as a statement by itself, and parsing gets very tricky if `{ 1, 2, 3 };` (an expression-statement) is valid but with a meaning completely different from `{ 1, 2, 3; };` (a compound-statement containing an expression-statement, followed by a null statement).

Comment: The existence of a trailing `;` inside the statement would differentiate those two to the parser. (Making it possible. Which is not the same things as making it a good idea.)

Answer (score 4):

`const auto` infers the type of your initializer list to be `const initializer_list<const char *>`, which can't be implicitly converted to `initializer_list<string>`, which is what you need to construct the `set` with the `initializer_list` constructor.  Just explicitly annotate the type and it will work:

```
initializer_list<string> abc = {a, b, c};

// works now
set<string> s2(abc);
```

EDIT: If you really can't use `initializer_list<string>` for some reason (why?), just use the iterator constructor instead of the `intializer_list` constructor:

```
const auto abc = {a, b, c};

// also works
set<string> s2(begin(abc), end(abc));
```

Comment: I was planning on putting this as an answer, but then I noticed the question explicitly states "I can't make any of a, b, c or abc use string as they are run-time constructed and this won't work for my case." I don't get and can't imagine why it won't work for the OP, though.

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I missed that.  There's no way to do it, then, since initializer_lists aren't subtypes even when their template parameters are.

Comment: Your edited version looks like a better approach to me. It doesn't address how to do assignment, but that's easy, given what you already put as an answer: assign a newly-constructed set, and trust the library's move-assignment operator to handle this efficiently. `s2 = set<string>(abc.begin(), abc.end());` (Also, `begin(abc)` and `end(abc)` is more general and would work even if `abc` is changed to an array.)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point.  I've edited the answer to use the non-member versions of `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Why can't I used `string`? Under some (hard to identify) conditions, it's impossible to assure that global variables that undergo run-time initialization will have been initialized before they are used. The most robust policy end up being to never uses non POD types as global variables.

Comment: @BCS Ah, that's fair enough. In that case, I'd make sure `abc` is an array, though. I *think* (but I'm not entirely sure) that if you use `initializer_list` (possibly coming from `auto`), it's not guaranteed to be statically initialised, although it may well be for your specific compiler.

Comment: I trust `initializer_list` to be statically initialised. But that still doesn't solve the `char*`->`string` issue which will require one of the other ugly solutions.

Comment: @BCS You could wrap the set-from-iterators in this answer in a helper function, if you prefer, so that you could do `set<string> s2 = make_set(abc);`. Would that look nicer to you?